# Hive case when clause efficiency

Tags: sql, hive

Is there difference between:

```
select
  case some_calculation() 
  when 'a' then 1
  when 'b' then 2
  else 0
  end
```

and

```
select
  case
  when some_calculation() ='a' then 1
  when some_calculation() ='b' then 2
  else 0
  end
```

I assume in the second version, the `some_calculation()` function will be evaluated twice.
I don't know how to verify that. Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not well-documented in Hive.  But it is well understood in the standard and in other databases.

In the second version, `some_calculation()` will definitely be evaluated multiple times.  A `case` expression is evaluated sequentially, so the second `when` is not evaluated until the first evaluates to false.

In the first version, the value should be evaluated once.

You can get a flavor for the difference by using a volatile functions, such as `random()`.  [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5e2a620d6c65fce2e37c69e9f16292d) illustrates the difference between the two approaches.  The first version never returns `NULL`.  The second returns lots of them.